# Can't read the full content in document.xml in openxml using c#

Tags: xml, openxml

How to read the document.xml file contents using OpenXML Sdk as a library.
i tried reading it, but some tags omitted in the object of MainDocumentPart.Document like

`<w:noproof/> and <w:footnotereference id="1"/>`

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

In openxmlsdk, if you use generic class OpenxmlElement instead of Paragraph class, the respective object avoids showing tags like `<w:noproof/> and <w:footnotereference id="1"/>`
So we need to use respective class for getting all the contents required from a Element in Openxml Sdk.
in this case if you use paragraph class, you can get the elements under it.